# Run a php function using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've got this php function located in the base /home/index.php

```
function addEmail() {
    $email = htmlentities($_POST['email']);
    if (wp_create_user($email, '7777777', $email)) echo 'OK';
    die();
}
```

I've also got this jQuery function located in /home/js/assets.js. The function checks to see if the email is valid and if so, should run the php function above.

```
$('#submit_btn').click(function () {
    var entered = $('#ms_id-2 > input#input_fld').val();
    if (isValidEmailAddress(entered) == false) {
        alert('Sorry, the email you entered is invalid. Please try again.');
        //console.log('No Validation!');
    } else {

        alert('Thank you. Your email address has been added to the list.');
    }
});
```

So basically, if the email is valid, I need the code to execute that function in index.php. What's the quickest way to do this?

Comment: You need Ajax: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/

Comment: To execute the server code from JavaScript , you need to do ajax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a PHP resource which invokes the desired logic.  Something as simple as this might do the trick depending on what you want it to do:

```
<?php
    require('index.php');
    addEmail();
?>
```

Then make an AJAX request to that resource:

```
$.post('theNewPage.php', { 'email' : entered }, function (response) {
    // handle the response in some way
});
```

The point is that JavaScript and PHP can't execute each other's code.  One is client-side, one is server-side.  They run at different times in different environments.  And they communicate by way of HTTP requests in this case.

So if you have code server-side that you want to execute, then you create a page which executes it and you make an HTTP request (in this case an AJAX request) to that page to execute it.  The `response` in the callback function in the JavaScript code will contain the result of that page (which in this case appears to be an `echo` of `'OK'`).  You'd examine that response and perform whatever action you intend to perform on the page.